# Reading the file line by line and re-create the file by Groovy

Tags: groovy, readfile

I have a text file with the format like below:

```
VER                                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
somelines here  
somelines here                                                          
VER                                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
somelines here  
somelines here  
somelines here
```

I want to create new file that not include *VER*, *----* and empty line by groovy, This is my code:

```
new File("C:/L_Groovy/L-Groovy/outmap.txt") << new File("C:/L_Groovy/L-Groovy/maps.txt").filterLine { !it.contains("VER") && !it.contains ("--") && ??? }
```

But it can not filter the space. Can anyone help me, I am a newbie in groovy.

Comment: Try !it.trim().isEmpty()

Comment: Thanks alot, It worked, But I have one more problem, at the end of new file it have null word. Any way so that I can delete it? Thanks!

Comment: Adding it as answer then - please accept. No idea where does null come from. Please provide a full example. Maybe `!null` will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following constraint should be helpful:

```
 !it.trim().isEmpty()
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Can you help me if I want to add .xml at the end of each line. Can I do that by groovy?

Comment: Possibly it can be done. But this is another question - ask it in a different post.